# Excel Delimiter changes to System default when creating a string based on multiple range values

Tags: excel, vba, settings, delimiter

Just a simple use case but it is bugging me big time!

```
A1: 2046.40
B1: 504.30
```

When i append multiple values from a table using
Worksheet(sheetname).Range("C1") = Worksheet(sheetname).Range("A1") & "," & Worksheet(sheetname).Range("B1")

i get the result delimeter according to the system settings = "."
result : 2046.40,504.30 (string)

When a user with a different language opens it up and runs this function the delimiter changes in the concat_value (C1) even though that A1 and B1 are displayed in the table using the "." as delimiter.

result other language
2046,40,504,30 (string)

i already tried the following codes:

```
Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"

Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Regards,

M

Answer (score 1):

### Decimal Separator Issue

- The following is working for me (I have the comma as the decimal separator).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DecimalSeparatorIssue()
    
    Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim sep As String
    sep = Application.DecimalSeparator
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetname)
    
    If sep = "." Then
        ws.Range("C1") = CStr(ws.Range("A1")) & "," & CStr(ws.Range("B1"))
    Else
        ws.Range("C1") = Replace(CStr(ws.Range("A1")), sep, ".") & "," _
                       & Replace(CStr(ws.Range("B1")), sep, ".")
    End If

End Sub
```

Additionally you could improve with the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function, e.g.:

```
Sub DecimalSeparatorIssue()
    
    Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim sep As String
    sep = Application.DecimalSeparator
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetname)
    
    If sep = "." Then
        ws.Range("C1") = Format(ws.Range("A1").Value, "0.00") & "," _
                       & Format(ws.Range("B1").Value, "0.00")
    Else
        ws.Range("C1") = Replace(Format(ws.Range("A1").Value, "0.00"), sep, ".") _
                       & "," _
                       & Replace(Format(ws.Range("B1").Value, "0.00"), sep, ".")
    End If

End Sub
```